# How do i use an image as a button function (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, uibutton, display, photoimage

Original Code:

```
search_button = Button(Frame3, text="Search", command=lambda: displaySelected(), bg="black", fg="white", font=('Arial', 10),padx=5,pady=5)
search_button.place(x=210, y=190)
```

How Original Output is like:
[Click to view for better visualisation (focus on the blue circle, ignore the other features there)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooArr.png)

What DisplaySelected() does:
[Basically show data based on the Country and Institution user selects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Fpq.png)

What I have tried:

```
search_pic = PhotoImage(file="search.png")
search_button = Button(Frame3, image=search_pic, command=lambda: displaySelected(), bg="black", fg="white", font=('Arial', 10),padx=5,pady=5)
search_button.place(x=210, y=190)
```

Basically, I want to do the same function, just that instead of having the button "search", I wish to replace it with a png file instead for better appearance. However, when i run the code, my png is not shown for some reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: @acw1668 nope hahah, thanks thou!! I tried following youtube tutorials for making an image to have a button function... however they are all showing .pack(). My code require .place() and my image its not in root, but in Frame3.

Comment: Is the code inside a function? If yes, it is the same issue as in the link.